# How does Angular2 import its components?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I am pretty new to AngularJS 2.0. When I read its quickstart guide and some other posts, there are `import` lines like this:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

I am wondering where `angular2/angular2` is. How do I know what the root directory (or structure) that I should import from is?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Guenter, `angular2/angular2` is not any path - rather, it is a predefined bundle of Angular2.  For this we have already imported
`system.js` before our angular in the `index.html` file.

If you look at the source code of [Angular](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js), you can see `System.register("angular2/core", ....` and that tells `systemjs` what to do. You can [find out more here.](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/System.register-Explained)

#### As Angular2 is no longer in beta, `angular2/angular2` does not exist.

Now, according to all of the updates, the list of imports is here:

```
import {Component, View, Directive, Input, Output, Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core'; 

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf  NgForm, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here 'angular2/angular2' is not a path but a predefined systemjs bundle for angular. In your index.html you have to load the system.js script  ahead of angular.

Comment: Thanks, once we have system.js, how do I know the bundle name is angular2/andgular2, isn't it still based on a folder structure?