# Angular2 import modules Error: TS2307

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I am going to write a simple hello word app with angular2 and systemjs to import module in phpStorm.

Here is the directory of my project:

```
ProjectName
     |--app
        |--app.ts
        |--app.js
     |node_modules
     |index.html
     |package.json
     |tsconfig.json
```

Here is a piece of code:

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
```

Question:
How does it know where to find this file? When I moved node_modules to app folder, there comes error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing: `angular2/platform/browser` and `angular2/core` are the names of modules, not the names of files. These modules loaded from the main Angular2 script, which could be node_modules/angular2/angular2.min.js or node_modules/angular2/angular2.dev.js.

If your code can access angular2.js, you can import many different Angular modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here `angular2/core` or `angular2/platform/browser` etc is not a path but a predefined systemjs bundle for angular.
if you look at the [source code](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js) of angular bundal you can see there's

```
System.register("angular2/core", etc ....
```

and that tells systemjs what to do. You can find [more here](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/System.register-Explained)...
for the same we have already imported system.js before our angular in the index.html.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34804834/5043867 List of imports for angular2

actuly system.js is a module loader there are variety of module loader are there but i have used `system.js` module loader like `commonJs`, `systemJs` etc.

both loader load the module in their own way like for example we took a code

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

this piece of code load by the commonJs in es6 like this

```
var core_1 = require('angular2/core'); ...
```

and systemJs bind this module like this:

```
System.register(['angular2/core'], function(exports_1) { ...
```

both the loader are good but quickstart uses SystemJS.